# Call to a member function getId() on null in /var/www/vhosts/<web>/<name>/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php

Tags: magento2, php, theme

This error appears when I try to go to the frontend of the Server web. The admin works perfectly.

And even further, if I use the local files and the local installation of Magento everything works fine.

I'm getting a HTTP error 500, and in the logs appears this code:

> Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getId() on null in /var/www/vhosts/a//vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php:751\nStack trace:\n#0
>    /var/www/vhosts///vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(684): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_getPhysicalTheme(Object(Magento\Theme\Model\Theme))\n#1 
>   /var/www/vhosts///vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(633): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_loadFileLayoutUpdatesXml()\n#2 /var/www/vhosts//vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(527): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->getFileLayoutUpdatesXml()\n#3 /var/www/vhosts///vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(506): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_fetchPackageLayoutUpdates('default')\n#4 /var/www/vhosts///vendor/magento/frame...\n'

The code that fails is this one:

```
protected function _getPhysicalTheme(\Magento\Framework\View\Design\ThemeInterface $theme)
{
    $result = $theme;
    while ($result->getId() && !$result->isPhysical()) {
        $result = $result->getParentTheme();
    }
    if (!$result) {
        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
            new \Magento\Framework\Phrase(
                'Unable to find a physical ancestor for a theme \'%1\'.',
                [$theme->getThemeTitle()]
            )
        );
    }
    return $result;
}
```

I run the commands:

```
rm -rf pub/static/*;
/opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php bin/magento setup:upgrade; 
/opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy; 
/opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy es_ES;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I was writing the question I managed to get it fixed:

I have modified my theme in `app\design\frontend\TemplateMonster\theme094\theme.xml`:

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Config/etc/theme.xsd">
<title>TemplateMonster Theme</title>
<parent>Magento/blank</parent> <!--Added-->
<media>
    <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
</media>
```

The `<parent>` tag was empty. Hope it helps someone.